# How to make this jquery countUP work with formatted numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery counter which works great. The only problem is, when I have a number in `data-target` which is formatted (eg. `10,000` instead of `10000`), it doesn't work and shows `NaN`.

I don't know what to modify, so it also counts up to `10,000,000` and not only works with `10000000`.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="10,000,000">0</div>
```

Comment: `10'000'000` isnt a number in any way `10,000,000` could be a number

Comment: updated it, it does not work with 10,000,000 either..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the number valid you need to remove the commas. You can use `replace()` to do that:

```
countTo = $this.attr('data-count').replace(/,/g, '');
```

> I want "10,000,000" to be displayed actually. It should count to "10,000,000" and output "10,000,000"

In that case you can use the function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/519413) to format the number within the output from `step` and `complete`:

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count').replace(/,/g, '');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(numberWithCommas(Math.floor(this.countNum)));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(numberWithCommas(this.countNum));
    }
  });
});

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="10,000,000">0</div>
```

Comment: Using a `data-*` attribute would be my suggestion as well.

Comment: @Pete not sure what you mean; OP is already using a `data` attribute

Comment: Hey. The thing is, I want "10,000,000" to be displayed actually. It should count to "10,000,000" and output "10,000,000". thanks! Sorry for not being clear enough..

Comment: Perfect! Works flawlessly. Thanks alot!! :))